# How can I set the recipients to bcc: when sending email programatically in Android App

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail

I followed the instructions in this link to set up sending email programatically via JavaMail API and GMail authentication.
[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app)
It works great, but I want to set the recipients to bcc: so I don't reveal their addresses to others on the list.  It is possible with this email library?

Thanks,
Glen

Comment: Been doing some research and found out that I can change the recipients property type from TO to BCC to CC.  Going to test it out but looks like it should work.  Here's the link to the information I found. [link](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Message.RecipientType.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the TO: filed to Message.RecipientType.TO   to Message.RecipientType.BCC   did indeed work in the GMailSender.java file.